# constant, but only for the remainder of this scope

Tags: c++

I sometimes encounter cases where it would make sense for a variable to be `const`, but only for the latter part of its scope.  For example, the first part of a block might set the value, and readability of the rest might be improved if it were clear that we were "done" setting that variable -

```
void foo() {
  int n;
  // Do things that result in initialization of n

  freeze n;  // Imaginary construct that declares "n" const for rest of scope

  // Later steps that depend on 'n' but do not change it
}
```

Is there any C++ idiom that captures this pattern?  Of course the latter part of the block could be moved to a separate function, but can it be done without moving things around as much?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to encapsulate the logic that generates `n` into a function of its own?  And then just `const int n = gimme_an_n();`.  You *could* do that inline with lambdas, but...  would you want to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of wrapping the immutable part as lambda, how about wrap the initialization part into lambda and get it as a `const int`? Then there is no chance to change the mutable `int n`.

```
void foo() {
  const int n = []() { ;
      // Do things that result in initialization of n
      return initialized_n;
  }();    

  // Later steps that depend on 'n' but do not change it
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Your "freeze" code could look like:

```
const int &refN = n;
```

and then you use `refN` instead of `n`. You could switch the names around.

There are more complicated solutions but you really have to ask yourself whether the gain is worth the pain. If your function is so complicated that you can't see at a glance whether you modified `n` then you need to refactor your code.

---

For example, to hide `n` you could do:

```
{
const int &_tmp = n;
const int &n = _tmp;

// rest of code

}
```

but you have to ask yourself if it is worth it. Whoever reads the code after you will wonder what you were smoking.

---

Another option is for your function to be:

```
const int n = setup_n();
```

where you offload the logic to another function, or a lambda:

```
const int n = [](){
   // ...logic...
   return finalized_value;
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a similar approach as that of [@PSkocik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34033070/3093378) (now deleted), you can capture the desired variables in an anonymous lambda and execute the latter. You can even define a variadic macro for this, so you can capture more than one variable using a relatively "clean" syntax:

```
#include <iostream>

#define WITH_CONST(...) [&, __VA_ARGS__]()   
#define DO ();

void foo() {
    int n{1}, m{2}, z{3};
    WITH_CONST(n, m) // captured variables are immutable in the scope below
    {
        //++n; // compile-time error
        //++m; // compile-time error
        ++z;   // z is mutable, can modify
        std::cout << n << " " << m << " " << z << std::endl;
    }
    DO;

    // n and m are not constant anymore
    ++n;
    ++m;
    std::cout << n << " " << m << " " << z << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    foo();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ced8be5f67bf243)

It doesn't make the variables constant for *all of the remainder* of the scope, but it lets you control the scope in which they are constant, and the latter, of course, can be extended to the end of the enclosing scope.